# Check all prerequisite software's and display message in one dialog - WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I would like to ask how to be done the installation prerequisite (.net framework and others) and display all the software not being installed in one dialog box instead of using condition and check the prerequisite, then display the warning message one by one.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use WiX's bootstrapper to provide all the prerequisites.